# Identify daily and monthly active users in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, users

Is there a convenient way to identify Daily / Weekly / Monthly Active User in Google Analytics?

I looked at the Active User and Cohort Reports both of which do not provide these metrics.

Since I'm interested in using these metrics with an App I wonder if using a custom dimension sending the according uuid is possible and in line with privacy policies? This data could then be used to count the number of days where sessions where greater than zero split by this custom dimension.

This sounds like an awkward solution though.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Analytics "Users" refers to active users.   Google won't count a user in reports unless they are active.    You can change the time period of the "Audience Overview" report to see the count of users (active users with at least one visit) during that time period.

Google Analytics allows you to set user identifiers as long as they don't contain any personally identifiable information (PII).   A UUID for each user as a custom dimension is fine as long as you can't plug that ID into your site to get PII such as the user's email address.